# Facebook picture modal in application

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I have a facebook iframe application which fetch the videos from a page. Is it possible to play those videos just like facebook does?
Like if we click the video/photo, it opens in a popup with comments and likes. Can I do the same thing in my app?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app will be inside Facebook and you cannot controll whats on the parent frame (Facebook in this case). You can only use your own modal windows inside the iframe.